# What happens when a module is required by more than one file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

For example, if there is one file **foo.js** with a variable **x** that is initialized with the number 1. **x is module.export**-ed from the file. Now if, foo.js is required in two other javascript files, and the value of x is changed in both these file with values 5 and 10 respectively. What exactly happens in this situation? Are there three different copies of x, or there is only one x, and depending on which file was run last, x will hold that value?

Comment: Did you try running it to see what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is immutable value, then it will be passed to both of these files as 1 in your scenario. If you change `x` later in other files. The original `x` would not change.

```
// foo.js
let x = 1;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('original: ', x);
}, 1000);
module.exports = x;
```

---

```
//a.js
let x = require('../lib/foo');
x = 2;
console.log('required x: ', x);
```

---

```
//output
require x:  2
original:  1
```

If `x` is mutable value, then no matter where change it, it will effect all `x` where using it.

```
// foo.js
let x = {
    a: 1
};
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('original: ', x);
}, 1000);
module.exports = x;
```

---

```
//a.js
let x = require('../lib/foo');
x.a = 2;
console.log('required x: ', x);
```

---

```
//output
require x:  {a: 2}
original:  {a: 2}
```

Comment: What do you mean with immutable and mutable values in this case? You should show two minimal examples illustrating that.

Comment: immutable value mean it's not changeable, otherwise it is mutable value.

Comment: I know the meaning of the those terms, but it does not make to much sense. If it is immutable, how could it be changed then? Without an example it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: It is less about mutable and immutable values, but about that JavaScript does not has the concept of _"direct references"_, like c++ has. If you call `require` you get a _"copy to a reference"_ of the object hold by `module.exports` at that time, and because of that `require('foo') = 1` would never change the `module.exports`. It essentially the same as writing `var x = 1; var y = x; y = 5`, where `x` will stay `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends whether x is reference type or value type. If x is reference type then mutation of it's property in one file gets reflected in other file.

In your example x is a value type so when you are changing its value it creates a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to require() are cached, so there shouldn't be a very big difference 
Also, calls to require() are blocking, so when they are processed nothing else is being run by Node.